# how to Filter Place Picker's results by PlaceType?

Tags: android, google-places-api

At the moment the Place Picker shows the map with all of the Places marked on the map. The list of places is at the bottom of the screen.

It would be great if I could filter the places by Place Type.

For example, the map and list would only show Taxis stands nearby.

My java code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;


public class PlacesAPIActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_api);

                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                Intent intent;
                try {
                    intent = builder.build(getApplicationContext());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_place_api, menu);

        return true;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data , this) ;

                String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s %s", place.getName(), place.getPhoneNumber());
                Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient">
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available. You may follow these open issue for updates:

[Issue 8484: Filter Place Picker by PlaceType](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827134)

Answer (score 0):

a Workaround could be to check the PlaceType and take action accordingly:

```
if (!place.getPlaceTypes().contains(1013)){ // 1013 = point of interest
 // Do action if Selected place not a point of interest
}
```